# Run Command From Within C# Mono Application in Linux

Tags: c#, linux, mono, console, terminal

I am wondering if a Mono C# application running in Ubuntu can somehow run a terminal command. For example, could the user give the program his or her password and then have the application run

```
sudo apt-get install application-name

(console requests password)

password

(console requests confirmation)

y
```

Preferably, this would be done without actually opening a terminal visible to the user, so that the application could provide the necessary feedback and manage the whole operation cleanly with as little user interaction as possible.

Is there a way to do that? If so, how? Let me know if clarification is needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be possible, you would just redirect the password to the [StandardInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput.aspx) stream of the **Process** class.

Comment: I am more specifically asking how to run commands with C#. The password situation is just an example. How can the program run a command? Thank you.

Comment: @Razick please read the answer again :-) You use the `Process` class for this.